# Restrict content length of grid view in wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

I have one list view, inside it having grid view.below is my out put and code.

[image]

Code:

```
<ListView 
    Grid.Column="0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    FontSize="20"
    Width="Auto"
    Foreground="Black"
    x:Name="DataBackup" Margin="262,414,262,0">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="20" />
                </Style>
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Modified Date/Time" 
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" 
                                    Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Converter={StaticResource starWidthConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}"
                                    />
            <GridViewColumn Header="User"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding User}"
                                    Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Converter={StaticResource starWidthConverter},ConverterParameter=2}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Location"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location}" 
                                    Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Converter={StaticResource starWidthConverter},ConverterParameter=3}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <local:SupportandMaintanceViewModel
                Date="02/07/2017 : 8:15"
                User="Admin"
                Location="Backup location will be shown here" />
</ListView>
```

Now what i need is , i need to restrict the content to be shown to particular length. (say for example the the content in the location column will be like "Backup location..." if we hover over it the complete content should be shown as a tool Tip)

can any one share your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

This will trim the text if the column width is not wide enough to show all the content:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Location"
                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Converter={StaticResource starWidthConverter},ConverterParameter=3}">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" ToolTip="{Binding Location}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```